# How to define global function inside document.ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to define a global function  inside `document.ready` which need to be called outside `document.ready`. I tried to define a function as

```
var global_fn={};
$(document.ready).function(){
   global_fn.my_function=function(){
    console.log('my function');
   };
global_fn.my_function();
}
global_fn.my_function();
```

The function call `global_fn.my_function();` inside `document.ready` works well, but outside it throws error: `Uncaught TypeError: global_fn.my_function is not a function`. What things I am missing?

**NB.** The reason for defining function inside `document.ready` is because of third party api I am using, which works only after dom is ready and the reason for making it global is because I want to call it in another js file.

Comment: the one outside fails because the document isn't ready yet, and therefore the function hasn't been defined yet. That makes total sense, and isn't a bug or a problem. If something needs it before the dom is ready, you'll have to define it before the dom is ready.

Comment: you are declaring it globally. However, the "outside" call to `global_fn.my_function();` is taking place before your `document.ready` event is firing

Comment: As @KevinB says - you're trying to define the function at some time in the future, but call it immediately (ie before it's been defined).  Unless there's something else missing from your code.

Comment: OMG! How can I be so much stupid. Sleepy effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work outside the `document.ready` function is that when it's out in the js file like that, the function gets executed before it gets created in `document.ready`.

It will be available in your other JS files as long as they don't try to access it before `document.ready`.